# Is there such thing as a 'half-plural'?

Tags: morphology, grammar, list-of-languages, grammatical-number

If yes, does any language have this feature?

By 'half-plural' I mean, somewhere between singular and plural, but not dual, trial, or quadral.

Comment: By 'half-plural' I mean, somewhere between singular and plural, but not dual, trial, quadral or even paucal.

Comment: By "between singular and plural" I don't mean dual. I mean, something not a lot, but not dual. For example, something think, that is not a lot of something.

Comment: Because person know, that are five things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93256/discussion-between-rock-and-sumelic).

Comment: Uncountable nouns?

Comment: No, because uncountable nouns can't count.

Comment: From your comment, I think you might believe that "paucal" is derived from "five". It isn't. It just means "a few, an unspecified small number >2", it has nothing to do with five. If you're a speaker of a Slavic language I could see this mistake as an easy one to make.

Comment: I'm not slavic speaker. My native language is Lithuanian. English is my second language.

Comment: That doesnt answer my question: **do you think that paucal means "relating to 5 items"**? The way you list it after dual, trial, and quadral, and your answer to sumelic make it seem like you do.

Comment: Yes, I think that paucal relates to five items

Comment: Rock, ok, that is the source of your confusion. "Paucal" just means "relating to a few items", and it is actually the most direct answer to your question. I asked your native tongue because I know that many languages have a number for 5 that sort of sounds like "paucal", such as Lithuanian *penki* or Polish *pięć*; and I suspected that you might have assumed that "paucal" was related.

Comment: I am sorry about paucal confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you may be looking for the **[paucal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number#Paucal)** number. [Paucal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paucal), from Latin *[paucus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paucus#Latin)*, "a few", means:

> pertaining to a language form referring to a few of something (three to around ten), as a small group of people; contrast singular, dual, trial and plural.

Comment: I am sorry about paucal confusion.

Comment: @Rock no need to be sorry, it's easy to see how you made the mistake. That's how we learn. If you think that this answer satisfies your question, you can mark it as the accepted answer so that future users can benefit from our discussion.